# I need a query that can calculate a value based on conditions

Tags: sql, plsql, sum, multiple-conditions

I have data such as:

| Type | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1000 |
| a | 5000 |
| b | 4000 |
| b | 2000 |
| c | 300 |

And would like to sum the amounts where Type is a and b, and minus the amounts where type is c.

I only know how to sum based on one condition, ie:
select sum(amount)
from xxxx
where type = 'a'

Do I need to do a sub-select or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `case` statement inside `sum`:

```
select sum(case when type in ('a', 'b') then amount when type = 'c' then -amount end)
from table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use GROUP BY:

```sql
SELECT
Type,
sum(Amount)
FROM table
GROUP BY Type
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUP
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/tutorial-agg.html

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE(Type , Amount) AS
 (
   SELECT 'a' ,1000 UNION ALL
   SELECT 'a' , 5000 UNION ALL
   SELECT 'b' , 4000 UNION ALL
   SELECT 'b' , 2000 UNION ALL
   SELECT 'c' , 300  
)
SELECT 
 SUM(CASE WHEN C.TYPE IN ('a','b')THEN C.Amount
     ELSE 0
END) -
SUM(CASE WHEN C.TYPE='c' THEN C.Amount
     ELSE 0
    END)
FROM CTE AS C
```

Answer (score 0):

for mariaDB

`SELECT
debit - credit
FROM
(SELECT sum(Amount) AS debit FROM Your_table WHERE Type IN ('a', 'b')) AS condition1,
(SELECT sum(Amount) AS credit FROM Your_table WHERE Type NOT IN ( 'a', 'b' )) AS condition2;`